# PDO Inserts Duplicate Data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code and whenever the function is called it is inserting the data twice.

The php that is calling the class/function:

```
$add_amenity = new listing;
echo $add_amenity->add_amenity($_POST['name']);
```

Here is the function:

```
    public function add_amenity($a)
{
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . db_host . ";dbname=" . db_name . "",db_user,db_password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

            $q = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO amenitylist (id,name,icon,isactive) VALUES ('',:a,'','1')");
            $q->bindParam(':a', $a);
            $q->execute();
            $this->_results = $dbh->lastInsertId();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->_results = "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

Comment: when you're calling your entity you're passing it two parameters but the function def has one. could be calling it twice? maybe

Comment: sorry, yes. I was mid change when I copied it over. I'm using the 1 param

Comment: That worked? or you've tried already

Comment: Already tried (still didn't work). I updated the code to show the accurate info. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There's nothing to suspect that this code is the culprit. You must be calling it twice by accident, maybe your page is refreshing twice without you noticing...?

Comment: ^^ Some causes of that are faulty rewrite rules loading the page twice, or harder to spot things like `<img>,<script>` tags with an empty `src=` attribute which causes the parent window's URI to be used, or a favicon.ico being called by the browser on each request and greedily sent by a rewrite rule to your PHP script. This is a common question around here, and it usually turns out to be one of these culprits.

Comment: Look in your access logs after refreshing the page. Do you see two hits to this script?

Comment: Wow. Yea, I feel like kicking my own butt. lol. I foolishly had a $.ajax wrapped inside of a $.post. Stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing me away from the php.